# Wrap around text inside frame (minipage) in Lyx

Tags: graphics, lyx, minipage

I want to insert a number of drop-shadowed frame inside a document and place (the same) graphic in the top left hand corner of each box. I would like the text in the rest of the box to wrap around this graphic - with some (arbitrary) margin.

What is the best way to do this? I had the graphic in a frame inside the frame but the text all went to the bottom of the frame, apart from the first paragraph.

**Update**The general idea is that I want something like this:

```
-----------frame---------------
|XXXGRAPHICXXXX   mytext here  |
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX   text again   |
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX   more text    |
|and the text wraps round the  |
|graphic.                      |
--------------------------------
```

I haven't added the listing that has been asked for as I am really hoping for a LyX-based solution as opposed to one in LaTeX. But I can add that is people really think it's helpful - it's an article class document, standard LyX template.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, a picture of what you have in mind might be useful.

Comment: If you want a LyX-based solution, give a LyX minimal example (http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) and please give your LyX version. Don't worry for this time, I see what you want and have an idea for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Insert > Float > Figure Wrap Float. You did not specify a caption in your ascii picture so I do not enter a caption.
2. Go to Insert > Graphics > Browse and select your graphic.
3. Go outside the figure wrap inset (e.g. control-right).
4. Insert the text you want.

If you stop here, you will get something like the following in LyX:
[image]

Which looks like this in pdf:[image]

To customize to how you want:

5. right-click where it says "wrap-figure" and go to settings (or go to Edit > Text Wrap Settings).
6. Change "placement" from Outer to Inner.
7. Change "Width" accordingly.

Here is a screen shot of the settings for my example:
[image]

Here is the pdf output:
[image]

You can download the example .lyx and .png file here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5x20abticsmfvm/wrapExample.lyx
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hdktembatsp11c/beamer-knight2.png

Just put them in the same folder and you are set.

Comment: What if you don't want a square limit but something like this: wrap text around more complex shapes, such as i.imgur.com/MsbsOVG.png or i.imgur.com/Apq8kdv.png or i.imgur.com/GxllBgA.png easier? I mean automatically wrapping around a shape without manually specifying coordinates for each line.

Comment: @skan I have no idea.