# Lyx: force Wrap Float not to cross a subsubsection

Tags: floats, lyx, wrap

I have a Wrap Float in Lyx with a graphics in it and the text of the current subsubsection on the side of the Wrap Float.

When the next subsubsection starts, it yet fills the space left next to the Wrap Float. I would like to force the new subsubsection to start under the Wrap Float and not to wrap it.

I have tried the `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package without success. Also I've tried the 'section' option of the package `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`, but it doesn't work on the subsubsections.

An example as Bernard suggested...
This is how the outcome looks
[image: current output]

this is how I want it to look

[image: my desired output]

and this is how it looks in the Lyx 2.1.3 editor

[image: the Lyx code]

the `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\` is making the white space, but I want a smarter way to do that which will not depend on figure and text size.

Comment: A minimal (non)working example would help to help.

Comment: added an example...

Comment: One typographic rule says that you should place a figure rather before the describing text. Another rule is that the huge white space you want is not so pretty. So what you want is not so usual. But have you tried koma? It is more flexibel in spacing matters.

Comment: I would like to sacrifice the look for the better organization to my subjective view. I was using 'Report (Standard Class with Extra Font Sizes)' document class and tried 'KOMA-Script Report'. It works the same way... or shall I do some more modifications except just changing the document class?

Comment: Please read this answer
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103281/wrap-around-text-inside-frame-minipage-in-lyx

Comment: @Mandrivagnome your link has nothing to to do with my question